# Counting the number of same elements in each class

Tags: r, count

According to the following table, I have many different teachers(10,11,12,...) with different ideas(1,2,... for example 1:Very Good, 2:Good,... ) of each class (1,2,3,...).
Some teachers don't have any idea about some classes.

```
class  Teacher-code  Opinion
     1   12            1
     1   13            1
     1   14            1
     2   11            3
     2   13            1
     3   10            1
     3   11            2
     3   12            1
     3   13            1
```

This is a sample of my table but I have many records. I want to have a symmetric matrix of teachers with counts of their same ideas about classes. for example, teacher 12 and 13 have the same idea in the class of 1 and 3, then the intersection elements of them are 2. Or teacher codes of 14 and 13 have just one same idea about the first class. I want to get the following matrix:

```
     [10] [11] [12] [13] [14]
[10]    0    0    1    1    0
[11]    0    0    0    0    0
[12]    1    0    0    2    1
[13]    1    0    2    0    1
[14]    0    0    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a base R solution based on a general approach taken to find common rows between data frames. Maybe this could be helpful.

Create a function that will find overlap in your dataframe between teachers that share other common values in certain columns (in this case, `class` and `Opinion`). With `merge` you can identify overlap, and `nrow` to count the overlapping rows.

Using `outer` you can generate a matrix of all teachers. The function passed to the product needs to be vectorized.

```
the_teachers <- sort(unique(df$Teacher_code))

get_num_classes <- function(x, y) {
  nrow(
    merge(
      df[df$Teacher_code == x, c("class", "Opinion")], 
      df[df$Teacher_code == y, c("class", "Opinion")]
    )
  )
}

mat <- outer(the_teachers, the_teachers, Vectorize(get_num_classes))
diag(mat) <- 0
dimnames(mat) <- list(the_teachers, the_teachers)
mat
```

**Output**

```
   10 11 12 13 14
10  0  0  1  1  0
11  0  0  0  0  0
12  1  0  0  2  1
13  1  0  2  0  1
14  0  0  1  1  0
```

**Edit**: Based on comment, there is interest in identifying the fraction of (teacher pairs sharing same opinions in same class) / (teacher pairs sharing same class). Building off the same logic, you could modify the function as below. A separate merge will determine the number of teachers sharing the same class. If this number is not zero, it will determine the number of opinions shared between the teacher pair. If there are no classes shared, the function will just return zero. Depending on size of data and concordance between teachers this may be optimized further.

```
get_num_classes <- function(x, y) {
  same_class <- nrow(
    merge(
      df[df$Teacher_code == x, "class", drop = F], 
      df[df$Teacher_code == y, "class", drop = F]
    )
  )
  if (same_class != 0) {
    same_opinion <- nrow(
      merge(
        df[df$Teacher_code == x, c("class", "Opinion")], 
        df[df$Teacher_code == y, c("class", "Opinion")]
      )
    )
    return(same_opinion / same_class)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution using `merge`. Upvoted your great answer!

Comment: Many thanks, your codes get the best result. I have another question. If I want to have this fraction in the matrix: the number of agreements between two teachers(your codes) /the number of classes which two teachers both said their opinions,  what should I add to your codes? for example 12, 13 have the same opinion in two classes(numerator ) and they both are contributing in 2 classes simultaneously (denominator), then we have 2/2=1 in the matrix.

Comment: @SA12 See edited answer - let me know if this is what you had in mind. Glad this was helpful!

Comment: Great! I sincerely appreciate your help and assistance. @Ben

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option by defining a user function `f`, where `aggregate` + `pmin` + `vecsets::vintersect` are applied:

```
library(vecsets)
f <- function(df) {
  u <- aggregate(. ~ Teacher_code, df, I)
  res <- do.call(
    pmin,
    lapply(
      u[c("class", "Opinion")],
      function(x) outer(x, x, FUN = function(...) lengths(Vectorize(vintersect)(...)))
    )
  )
  `dimnames<-`(`diag<-`(res, 0), rep(list(u[["Teacher_code"]]), 2))
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(df)
   10 11 12 13 14
10  0  0  1  1  0
11  0  0  0  0  0
12  1  0  0  2  1
13  1  0  2  0  1
14  0  0  1  1  0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is not accurate in big data. But thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I mean its some pretty hideous code (I'm sure someone can do something better) but I think it gets you the result you need (this isn't homework is it -.- ?). Also in the future it makes life easier if you provide data using `dput()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


dat <- tibble(
    class = c( 1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    Teacher_code = c(12,13,14,11,13,10,11,12,13),
    Opinion = c(1,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1)
)

dat2 <- complete(dat, class, Teacher_code)
classes <- unique(dat2$class)
teachers <- unique(dat2$Teacher_code)
len_teachers <- length(teachers)

mat <- matrix(nrow = len_teachers, ncol = len_teachers)

for(i in seq_along(teachers)){
    for( j in seq_along(teachers)){
        same_opinion <- 0
        for(k in classes){
            opinion_i <- dat2 %>% filter(Teacher_code == teachers[[i]] , class == k) %>% pull(Opinion)
            opinion_j <- dat2 %>% filter(Teacher_code == teachers[[j]] , class == k) %>% pull(Opinion)
            same_opinion <- same_opinion + (opinion_i == opinion_j & !(is.na(opinion_i) | is.na(opinion_j)))
        }
        mat[i,j] <- same_opinion
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get the appropriate result by your codes, But thanks for your attention. No, it isn't homework, it's research.